# Error Using “cd /Desktop , ~cd /Desktop” Commands in Ubuntu Console

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cd

I downloaded Ubuntu from Windows Store. I made necessary adjustments but I can't use "cd" and "~cd"commands to reach my desktop it gives error.It says"No such file or directory". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) uses a bit of a different environment than your normal Windows machine does. Your computer's C: drive can be browsed with `/mnt/c`, so you can get to your desktop using `/mnt/c/Users/yourusername/Desktop`.

Comment: I've never used WSL, but didn't whoever designed it miss the golden opportunity there to be able to use `~/Desktop` ?